# unknown type name <derived class name>

Tags: c++, derived

I am trying to compile the implementation file for a base class that has functions that operate themselves on a type that is derived from a different base class. The outline is the following:

- Element (base class) [uses TransitionList)
- Transition (derived from Element)
- List (base class)
- TransitionList (derived from List)

element.h

```
ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include "transitionList.h"

class Element{

    //other code

    public:

        Element();

        virtual ~Element();

        virtual TransitionList* get_successor();

        virtual void set_successor(TransitionList* e);

    //other code

};

#endif
```

element.cpp

```
#include "transitionList.h"
#include "element.h"

Element::Element(){}
Element::~Element(){}

// other code

TransitionList* Element::get_successor(){}
Element::set_successor(TransitionList* e){}
```

transitionList.h

```
#ifndef TRANSITION_LIST_H
#define TRANSITION_LIST_H

#include "list.h"
#include "transition.h"

class Transition;

class TransitionList: public List {

    public:

        TransitionList();
        ~TransitionList();

        // other code
};

#endif
```

transitionList.cpp

```
#include "transitionList.h"


TransitionList::TransitionList(){}
TransitionList::~TransitionList(){}

// other code
```

transition.h

```
#ifndef TRANSITION_H
#define TRANSITION_H

#include "element.h"
#include "transitionList.h"


class TransitionList;

class Transition: public Element {

    public:

        Transition();
        ~Transition(){}

    // other code

#endif
```

transition.cpp

```
#include "transition.h"
#include "element.h"
#include "transitionList.h"


Transition::Transition(){}

// other code
```

So, when I try to compile element.cpp I get

```
error: unknown type name 'TransitionList'
```

Which I don't understand, because it is included in element.h. I guess the question isn't really helpful, but, I don't really know what might be needed.

Comment: This is an order-of-inclusion issue: include transitionList.h -> include transition.h -> include element.h -> include transitionList.h (no-op because of include guards) -> define class `Element` The `TransitionList` class is not declared when the class `Element` is defined because of this order.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I added class TransitionList; before the definition of Element and it compiled. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you try to reduce your dependencies. For example, the parts of element.h you've shown do not need the definition of `TransitionList`, therefore the header transitionList.h is not required in element.h, a forward-declaration is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out. I didn't know you could forward declare without including the respective classes header.